# Return value to trigger quit in safari

Tags: javascript, applescript

Is there a way to `return value` or `listen for event` using `AppleScript` that will occur in JavaScript code to know when the `do JavaScript` has finally completed and for example, `tell` browser to quit.

**Edit**

```html
tell application "Safari"
 tell window 1
  set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:""}
  do JavaScript "" in current tab
 end tell
 quit
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait. A `do JavaScript` event in Safari won't return until the Javascript code has completed. You can verify this by running:

```
tell application "Safari"
  do JavaScript "alert('hello')" in first tab of first window
  display dialog "Done"
end tell
```

Note that the "Done" dialog doesn't appear until the JS dialog has been dismissed.

Comment: in my case I have a loop inside JS logic and from what I've experienced the AppleScript actually, quits safari before the JS has been fully executed.

Comment: Are you sure the JS didn't complete? What makes you certain?

Comment: JS script used in this case contains some setTimeouts which will take it to execute at least 1 minute in the scenario I've provided above the Safari opens, the script starts and then Safari instantly quits since there is no delay. At this moment I resolve this issue by providing a delay of more or less equal that browser requires to execute the task.

Comment: @AdrianSol Working as expected. Calling `setTimeout()` doesn't wait for the timeout to fire -- that's the whole point, after all.

Comment: I hadnested timeouts inside of JS code (5-6 of nestings) so I pretty sure that can be cause of the behavior I did experience, otherwise I would never create this question :D But anyway few days later I refactored the original JS into more AppleScript logic while doing only basics with JS and your statement now perfectly applies for this question. Thank you a lot for your support.